# How to ensure array is deleted inside a function when there is an exception caught in calling function?

Tags: c++

In the example below, how do you make sure that the first array is deleted when the allocation for the second array fails? (With deliberate mistake of "-3" to cause an exception to be thrown for demonstration purposes).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int n1, int n2)
{
    int *array1 = new int[n1];
    cout << "alloc 1" << endl;
    int *array2 = new int[n2];
    cout << "alloc 2" << endl;
    // Something useful with these arrays goes here!
    delete[] array1;
    cout << "deleted 1" << endl;
    delete[] array2;
    cout << "deleted 2" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        func(10, -3);
    }
    catch(bad_alloc ex)
    {
        cout << "bad alloc" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or is "array1" deleted automatically?

**Update**

I can't use "std::vector" as I'm calling legacy functions, as well as my own functions that both use arrays.

A messy but functional **solution**:

```
void func(int n1, int n2)
{
    int *array1;
    int *array2;
    int v = 0;
    try
    {
        array1 = new int[n1];
        cout << "alloc 1" << endl;
        v = 1;
        array2 = new int[n2];
        cout << "alloc 2" << endl;
        // Something useful with these arrays goes here!
    }
    catch(bad_alloc ex)
    {
        cout << "bad alloc func" << endl;
        if (v == 1)
        {
            delete[] array1;
            cout << "deleted 1" << endl;
        }
        throw;
    }
    delete[] array1;
    delete[] array2;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        func(10, -3);
    }
    catch(bad_alloc ex)
    {
        cout << "bad alloc main" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a`std::vector` instead to guarantee that behavior.

Comment: or use smart pointers instead of raw pointers!

Comment: `array1` is not deleted automatically. Yet another reason to use vector instead of arrays because then this hard work has been done for you.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` if you can't use a vector for some reason

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is meant by Resource Acquisition is Initialization (RAII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)

Comment: If your legacy functions take an `int*` you can use `vec.data()` to get that pointer.

Comment: what keeps you from checking right at the top of your ```func``` function whether the inputs are valid? And if the inputs are not valid, you can throw a ```bad_alloc``` exception yourself.

Comment: If you provide your own solution, then you should post it as an answer and see how people vote it compared to other answer... It is in fact messy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). It will automatically release the memory resource.

You can access the underlying pointer with the [data()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) member function, so you can pass the data to legacy functions.

Comment: Oh, I heard a long time ago that the std library was buggy. So I try not to use it. I guess it's been fixed now?

Comment: yes, it was buggy 20 years ago on Visual C++. But it works very well now... use strings & vectors, or C++ isn't that interesting to use as a language

Answer (score 0):

You could put the second allocation inside a try … catch block:

```
void func(int n1, int n2)
{
    int* array1 = new int[n1];
    cout << "alloc 1" << endl;
    int* array2;
    try {
        array2 = new int[n2];
    }
    catch (bad_alloc ex) {
        delete[] array1;
        throw;
    }
    cout << "alloc 2" << endl;
    // Something useful with these arrays goes here!
    delete[] array1;
    cout << "deleted 1" << endl;
    delete[] array2;
    cout << "deleted 2" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Then, you can clean up the first (successful) allocation before re-throwing the exception for your calling function to catch!

Comment: @OP 'Update' - You can use std::vector as an argument for a function that expects an array: just pass "&elem[0]" for the argument, as the standard guarantees that elements are contiguous.

Comment: I think what you are trying to get at is something like the solution I have given in the edited question.